# Pass data to another Controller and save?

Tags: swift, xcode

The following code passes variables to destVC, and it works. But when I close destVC the variables clean up. Is there any way to save these variables?

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

              if let destVC = segue.destination as? ViewControllerGpsMaps {

                if (baseCoordinatesSaveNow == true) {

                    destVC.baseCoordinatesSaveNow = true
                }
                destVC.actualDestinationLatitude = Double(waypointlatitude.text!)
                destVC.actualDestinationLongitue = Double(waypointlongitude.text!)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have your tried with UserDefaults - https://medium.com/better-programming/userdefaults-in-swift-4-d1a278a0ec79?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `UserDefaults` like below:

To **save** the data use below code(on source VC):

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(Double(waypointlatitude.text!), forKey: "latitude")
```

To **retrieve** the data use below code(on destination VC):

```
 UserDefaults.standard.double(forKey: "latitude")
```

In a similar way you can do for longitude.

To **remove** data use below code:

```
UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "latitude")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two simple methods:
Method 1: 
Save data in user defaults like this:

```
//To save data
   UserDefaults.standard.set(waypointlatitude.text, forKey: "lat")
//To get data
   let lat = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "lat")
```

Method 2:
Save data in global variables. Make class for global and take shared instance like this:

Global class:

```
class global: NSObject {
    static let shared = global()
    var lat: Double?
}
```

To set data in global:

```
global.shared.lat = Double(waypointlatitude.text ?? 0.0)
```

To get data from global:

```
let lat = global.shared.lat
```

global can be accessed anywhere using shared instance.